# Real base conversion

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, base-conversion

We've had a few challenges for base conversion, but all of them seem to apply to integer values. Let's do it with real numbers!

## The challenge

Inputs:

- A real **positive number** *x*, expressed in base 10. This can be taken as a double-precision float or as a string. To avoid precision issues, the number can be assumed to be greater than 10<sup>−6</sup> and less than 10<sup>15</sup>.
- A **target base** *b*. This will be an integer from 2 to 36.
- A **number of fractional digits** *n*. This will be an integer from 1 to 20.

Output: the **representation** of *x* in base *b* with *n* fractional digits.

When computing the output expression, the digits beyond the *n*-th should be **truncated** (not rounded). For example, `x = 3.141592653589793` in base `b = 3` is `10.0102110122...`, so for `n = 3` the output would be `10.010` (truncation), not `10.011` (rounding).

For *x* and *b* that produce a finite number of digits in the fractional part, the **equivalent infinite representation** (truncated to *n* digits) is also allowed. For example, `4.5` in decimal can also be represented as `4.49999...`.

Don't worry about **floating point errors**.

## Input and output format

*x* will be given without leading zeros. If *x* happens to be an integer you can assume that it will be given with a zero decimal part (`3.0`), or without decimal part (`3`).

The output is flexible. For example, it can be:

- A string representing the number with a suitable separator (decimal point) between integer and fractional parts. Digits `11`, `12` etc (for *b* beyond 10) can be represented as letters `A`, `B` as usual, or as any other distinct characters (please specify).
- A string for the integer part and another string for the fractional part.
- Two arrays/lists, one for each part, containing numbers from `0` to `35` as digits.

The only restrictions are that the integer and fractional parts **can be told apart** (suitable separator) and use the **same format** (for example, no `[5, 11]` for the list representing the integer part and `['5', 'B']` for the list representing the fractional part).

## Additional rules

- [Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Output is shown as a string with digits `0`, ..., `9`, `A`, ... , `Z`, using `.` as decimal separator.

```
x, b, n                    ->  output(s)

4.5, 10, 5                 ->  4.50000 or 4.49999
42, 13, 1                  ->  33.0 or 32.C
3.141592653589793, 3, 8    ->  10.01021101
3.141592653589793, 5, 10   ->  3.0323221430
1.234, 16, 12              ->  1.3BE76C8B4395
10.5, 2, 8                 ->  1010.10000000 or 1010.01111111
10.5, 3, 8                 ->  101.11111111
6.5817645, 20, 10          ->  6.BCE2680000 or 6.BCE267JJJJ
0.367879441171442, 25, 10  ->  0.94N2MGH7G8
12944892982609, 29, 9      ->  PPCGROCKS.000000000
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63978/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-luis-mendo).

Comment: for `42, 13, 1` can we have `33` instead of `33.0`?

Comment: @LiefdeWen No, an essential part of the challenge is that the output must have `n` decimal digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
*×⁵b⁸ḞðṖḣ⁹,ṫø⁹N‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//KsOX4oG1YuKBuOG4nsOw4bmW4bij4oG5LOG5q8O44oG5TuKAmP///zE2/zEy/zEuMjM0)

Note that singletons are printed as the element in the output.

Comment: Hey, what happened to your picture?

Comment: @LuisMendo some people cannot render it, since it was connected to Facebook

Comment: You know you can upload a picture here, right? Those default ones are so impersonal

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES8), <s>81</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```js
f=
(x,b,n,g=x=>x.toString(b))=>g(x-x%1)+'.'+g(x%1).substr(2,n).padEnd(n,0)
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(+x.value,b.value,n.value)><input id=x><input type=number min=2 max=36 value=10 id=b><input type=number min=1 max=20 value=10 id=n><pre id=o>
```

Works for `x` between `1e-6` and `1e21`, `b` from `2` to `36` (exactly as required) and `n` from `1` to anything from `10` to `48` depending on the base before floating-point errors creep in. Edit: Saved 7 bytes with help from @Birjolaxew. Saved a further 3 bytes with help from @tsh. Previous 74-byte version also worked with negative numbers:

```js
f=
(x,b,n,[i,d]=`${x.toString(b)}.`.split`.`)=>i+`.`+d.slice(0,n).padEnd(n,0)
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(+x.value,b.value,n.value)><input id=x><input type=number min=2 max=36 value=10 id=b><input type=number min=1 max=20 value=10 id=n><pre id=o>
```

Comment: How does one do base conversion with regex?!?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm not, it's just a golfier (hopefully) way of extracting up to `n` "digits" from a string.

Comment: Then what *is* the core logic of your function?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Why, JavaScript's built-in base conversion function of course. (Hint: look at where I use the base parameter.)

Comment: Oh it says `.toString(b)`...dumb me >_<

Comment: -1 bytes by using `\.` instead of `[.]`. [-4 bytes by using `.split` instead of `.match`.](https://goo.gl/znQJNZ)

Comment: @Birjolaxew `\.` doesn't work because it's a string not a regex but I love your idea of appending a `.`! (You missed some extra savings though.)

Comment: @Neil Ah right, my mistake. Good catch on those extra savings - I always forget that you can `.split\`\`` (what even is that anyway :P )

Comment: Clever use of `$ .split()` rather than standard `.split()`. Otherwise you have to do a short circuit trick and end up gaining one character:
 `f=(r,b,n,[i,d]=r.toString(b).split`.`)=>i+'.'+(d||'0').slice(0,n).padEnd(n,0)`

Comment: `(x,b,n,g=x=>x.toString(b))=>g(x-x%1)+'.'+g(x%1).slice(2,n+2).padEnd(n,0)`

Comment: @tsh Nice but you forgot to use `substr`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>153</s> <s>149</s> <s>144</s> <s>137</s> <s>135</s> 109 bytes

```python
def f(x,b,m):
 i=int(x);s=[];t=[]
 while i:s=[i%b]+s;i/=b
 while m:m-=1;x=x%1*b;t+=[int(x)]
 return s or[0],t
```

Hadn't noticed I can just return the digits as numbers, so that makes it a lot simpler. Returns two lists of digits, first for the integer part, second for the fractional.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU7LboMwELzzFb5U2IG62JiHjZwfiXKAJiiugomMq1JF@Xa6pkQ9VfKuNbM7s3P79pfR8mU5nXvU4znt0oGoCBltrMczaSZ9ODYeWoS@LuZ6RkYBZV66YzI15k13T35Qw6tmzaznF7brGp/A1moBSnf2n86iCY3ukB1Tv7T62g7dqUVWvV8ctomoE2z3mmVkV5HIbePdrGIa04/RWBxv/9DecJtOhPSjA0dj0UyikN6v6W1If3NwOr7Pas@Kx71Te@g2dIUQurtHTEE8tKDQoNGg0jZ12uFdv5kQEkUeC1qkiGUpKkhAHEAOFUBOmWCF5GWRF7WsJPDw6n9Gq02YMcpzAaCE4iuRhRt8k/6ip1FJi5pVpQgL2dMho3lZ1ZUUgrGKiRCK/9lz4GvJZc3LTMIESpLlBw)

Comment: In case it helps: I've added a note that you only need to support numbers greater than `1e-6` (and less than `1e15`, as before)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
->\x,\b,\n{+x .base(b,n)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##fVBda9tAEHy/X7GEppEaeXO79yFdQlOwCA4tbUP7GIViuwoYbMlYSXBJ88v61j/mrmyJljh04O643ZmduVuWq7nf3DclPHicnqnFD3g9GTflYFpXD@WqmdUVvN0Mzot1UkySono8XgO2hGiSVPHTZnl/B0eX5Xxeg0ir8aKEWQNHCTwfYpg8GXTOEjujXeZMAkYnkJ4pJVOiGNZrYLnc1iuYz6qyieLfv3BaLybRCRTfj@G6wPa8eQcnMS7Gy1N4c60R@QYeFQiWq1l1dwsHh6wbgEPebaeyN0V1kMDPV9/2ckVtFWL1tLHoEiAJ5OA5BucA0tYCkHAWbRAoyyKQVxC8qDAGt3TDmCuDZMkF9s64LKShfXwCWc8ljZo0E2l6ibpN1o9FbdgwkzVaEbKx0vSyeD8CoRlepD7PhtYEp8RFJnHnu8@WCEh6hzb5tqBph05t/q/uyR5dRqm3rZ/u0v9D9jjML9hnvVN3T98LlEbj0ywN1hKlZNtv5u4HWq3GYD/xx9FlOsoUsdCywCFjr4MQZYW/PldX@ejL5/zDV9Q9/gA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
-> \x, \b, \n {
  +x            # make sure it is a Numeric
  .base( b, n ) # do the base conversion
}
```

Note that the space is so that it is parsed as `(+x).base(b,n)`
not `+( x.base(b,n) )`.

Comment: In case it helps: I've added a note that you only need to support numbers greater than `1e-6` (and less than `1e15`, as before)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->x,b,n{(x*b**n).round.to_s(b).insert(~n,?.)}
```

#### Why?

Since b^n in base b is 10^n, we multiply x by that number, and then add the decimal point where it belongs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/LCsIwELz7FT22JS7J5n1QP6QEaX2AB6NUCxUfv1431eJJ2IGdmc1kt@2a27BfDPNlzxoW73lfNmUZC2hPXdzC9bS@5E0Bh3jZtdf8FdkKiudQVQo0ywRnmQ5sVikkIgmJSBBKaI9GS@289aRTuT/WGJM8ASgVEUPAUeDpD/w@/bApyIB2whqVBviUwEEa66xXSggrVFoKf/FIuvPoHRruySH4EOBYn@@Pmm7fPM5ZNTYs23@aEJ7DGw)

Comment: -1 byte + bugfix by replacing `.round` with `.to_i`; this fixes the last digit of the output for ones where it doesn't match the test outputs. -1 more byte by using `.insert ~n,?.`, without parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 158 bytes

since this challenge allready got a very nice answer in mathematica by @KellyLowder, I tried to produce (with a different approach) **the exact results as shown in the test cases**

```
ToUpperCase[""<>Insert[StringReplace[ToString@BaseForm[#,p]&/@PadRight[#&@@(d=RealDigits[#,p=#2]),w=(#3+d[[2]])][[;;w]],"\n "<>ToString@p->""],".",d[[2]]+1]]&
```

**input**

> [12944892982609, 29, 9]

**output**

> PPCGROCKS.000000000

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>157</del> 152 bytes

Needs 64 bits `long int` for this to work with larger test cases.

*-5 bytes thanks to Peter Cordes*

```
#define P r=99;i=l=x;do{z[--r]=48+7*(l%b>9)+l%b;}while(l/=b);printf(z+r)
long i,r,l;char z[99];f(x,b,n)double x;{P;putchar(46);while(n--){x=(x-i)*b;P;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LboMwEEX3fIWVqpIdBopfgGXRb8g@ySK8EkvURFbSoiC@nTpptyXd2PLonDvXVXSsqnl@qZvW2AZtkCuU0qboikHX/XjbRpHbFyIPszXuXst3RUJ/6enrZLoGd29FSfTZGXtp8S10JOh6e0SPw4CDTleng0O3rVJ73eIBSrCk7q9l16BBjxt9vl7uBBYp0T@RNorIOBR4iAxZl3qjp2n28ejjYCz@7E1N0Bgg1GIRS6AJSKL987fCauf1aGdXj6FnWAyUA11ieEwFlYqlEjjk/yO5zFWmONwbLBk0ZlwATYGyRSzxf2HLyx/Mk4JpLHOapUICYgmg5W5JzNMsz5QQlGZUCOYl@UyizPO5YipnaaJiryhA6m/DNZersyjRwRTM3w)

edit: a few bytes can be shaved if it's allowed to output two strings separated by a newline separator:

### 149 bytes:

```c
#define P r=99;i=l=x;do{z[--r]=48+7*(l%b>9)+l%b;}while(l/=b);printf(z+r)
long i,r,l;char z[99];f(x,b,n)double x;{P;puts("");while(n--){x=(x-i)*b;P;}}
```

edit: this submission is not the longest one, yay!

Comment: You can use `printf(z+r)` if it doesn't contain any `%` characters.  (This is code-golf; security and good practices go out the window :P).  You could also use `puts(z+r)` to get a newline for free (saving the `puts("")` in the second version).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about providing a char* directly as a pattern, this indeed saves quite a few bytes :-)
I cannot use puts(z+r) in the second version since that would mean each decimal will be printed on a newline

Comment: Ah, that last part wasn't obvious without an ungolfed version with comments.

Comment: `float` is shorter than `double`, but it seems the question does require a `double` or string input.

Comment: Using floats produce erroneous results, especially for the last test case.
Also, to handle 10^15 numbers, if I strictly follow C standards, then I should use `long long` integers. Here I'm just taking advantage of 64 bits compilers ;-)

Comment: I was just thinking of taking full advantage of the "Don't worry about floating point errors." in the question.  Of course it reduces precision a lot. :P  Anyway, good point that this isn't just C, it's "C with 64-bit `long`", which is fine as long as you say so in the answer.  Note that gcc targeting the 64-bit Windows ABI has 32-bit `long`, because it's a feature of the ABI, not up to the compiler.  (So "gcc" doesn't imply 64-bit long)

Comment: Thinking about it, using "64 bits long integers" makes no sense at all and this cannot be justified. I'll edit my answer right now and define proper `long long` ints.

Comment: No need for that.  Some common implementations of C do have 64-bit `long`, and according to code-golf rules that's all you need for your answer to be valid.  (Also, it's common for C and C++ code-golf answers to assume 64-bit `long`, since that's what Try It Online uses.)  I'd suggest rolling back your edit, and just adding a note like "`long` must be 64-bit for this to support the larger test-cases."

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), 68 bytes

```py
def f(n,b,k):y=n.str(b).split('.')+[''];return y[0],(y[1]+'0'*k)[:k]
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwNw0EKgCAQAMB70B-87W6JmES0RS8RL1FCGBJqB39fA3OcXniMcpeBlrpFlUvCnVR-7qsgKKDeArg1neVNUVSrncRqB9eDhi6QXYJrm7Z50hULehwMj-PMhmczaZbC_JnoAydMG-g=&lang=sage)

Comment: In case it helps: I've added a note that you only need to support numbers greater than `1e-6` (and less than `1e15`, as before)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 47 Bytes

```
TakeDrop@@r[#,#2,#3+Last@(r=RealDigits)[#,#2]]&
```

Calling `RealDigits` twice to first figure out the number of digits to the left of the decimal.

Comment: In case it helps: I've added a note that you only need to support numbers greater than `1e-6` (and less than `1e15`, as before)

Comment: I thought the question was just asking for `TakeDrop@@RealDigits[##]`& but then I realized I had misread things - your solution seems optimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 188 bytes

```hs
f=fromIntegral
g 0 _=[]
g n p=g(div n p)p++[mod n p]
z=(!!)(['0'..'9']++['A'..'Z']++['.'])
h x p l|(i,d)<-properFraction x=z<$>(g i p++[36]++(last$g(floor$d*(f p**f l))p:[0<$[1..l]|d==0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFta9swEP48/4qrCViKXaE3v4W4sIQuG1u3sn6bZ4apnRemxMJxN1P637NznYYdOvTonudOJ922PP6ujTmd1tm6bfafDl29aUvjbIDDrywvEBzAZhtS7f4MiFrfz/dNNeDCec7I1RUlucc9xrzUK5D03g/4x4iZV1BnCz1YMC9kF1R0fm3bxtbth7Z87HbNAfrseT65IRvYwVBbRZhITHnsJhuyNk3TTqopWYOdTtdgKLWznM8nuWDMFC9VlvGC0lPdl3tr6iNkkBPNwgAEDwA3Fw8czaUBEC0xrtAxrhQbg4oJLcJURqEKkzRO1WvekO6iREklpdBq1AomlUYyQsdarmBqcRtHy2ShVRqOEj7cjmQy8ByPgo/2H60uNBNne2UjFiYijvRQgZ@biNhieSuj5FKCMxXFSZxqLUQs9PAo@dYxZ6n@Ku9WH@NVMt4nUZekMk1kxFNUouNy7@@Xq@/flp8fGOeX/grH2Ze7A35i1Tjv9qW9A/KT9IENTFDT6xuwT91D1345wATcurf1Y1dXM3B9v/Z9NwAc6FNpZi74PpDjtvmLuvPsKYW3GZ3@AQ)

`g` converts a number to a list representing that number in a given base

`z` maps integers to letters (`36 = .`)

`h` applies the previous functions to the integer and fractional part of a number.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 127 bytes

```
g(a)==floor(a)::INT;f(a:Float,b:PI,n:NNI):Any==(b<2 or n>28=>%i;x:=g(a);radix(x,b)+radix(g((a-x)*b^n),b)::RadixExpansion b/b^n)
```

results

```
(4) -> f(%e,2,10)
   (4)  10.1011011111
                                                   Type: RadixExpansion 2
(5) -> f(%e,3,10)
   (5)  2.2011011212
                                                   Type: RadixExpansion 3
(6) -> f(%e,35,10)
   (6)  2.P4VBNEB51S
                                                  Type: RadixExpansion 35
(7) -> f(1.4,35,10)
   (7)  1.DYYYYYYYYY
                                                  Type: RadixExpansion 35
(8) -> f(%pi,3,8)
   (8)  10.01021101
                                                   Type: RadixExpansion 3
(9) -> f(%pi,5,10)
   (9)  3.032322143
                                                   Type: RadixExpansion 5
(10) -> f(1.234,16,12)
   (10)  1.3BE76C8B4395
                                                  Type: RadixExpansion 16
```

It has a little problem for final zero example

```
 f(4.5,10,5)
```

Would return '4.5' and not '4.50000'

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 566 bytes

```
c:=alphanumeric()::List Character
f(a:INT,b:PI):List Character==(r:=[];repeat(y:=a rem b;r:=cons(c.(y+1),r);a:=a quo b;a=0=>break);r)
g(x)==floor(x)::INT
F(x)==>for i in 1..#x repeat z:=concat(z,x.i)
w(a:Float,b:PI,n:NNI):String==
  z:="";b<2 or b>36 or a<0=>z
  ip:=g(a);    fp:=g((a-ip)*b^n)
  ipb:=f(ip,b);fpb:=f(fp,b);cnt:=n-#fpb
  for i in 1..cnt repeat fpb:=cons(c.1,fpb)
  F(ipb);z:=concat(z,".");F(fpb)
  z

h(a,b,n)==>(n>=0 and b>0=>(nd123:=10+g(n*log_2(b)/log_2(10));mxv123456:=digits(nd123::PI);res78484:=w(a,b,n);digits(mxv123456);res78484);"")
```

it was particular difficult this question; afther some time in write something, the right results it seems
generate using one macro for preserve digits()... it is not golfed too much...results:

```
(7) -> h(4.5,10,5)
   (7)  "4.50000"
                                                             Type: String
(8) -> h(42,13,1)
   (8)  "33.0"
                                                             Type: String
(9) -> h(%pi,3,8)
   (9)  "10.01021101"
                                                             Type: String
(10) -> h(%pi,5,10)
   (10)  "3.0323221430"
                                                             Type: String
(11) -> h(1.234,16,12)
   (11)  "1.3BE76C8B4395"
                                                             Type: String
(12) -> h(0.367879441171442,25,10)
   (12)  "0.94N2MGH7G8"
                                                             Type: String
(13) -> h(12944892982609,29,9)
   (13)  "PPCGROCKS.000000000"
                                                             Type: String
(14) -> h(6.5817645,20,10)
   (14)  "6.BCE267JJJJ"
                                                             Type: String
```

the real target is one function that convert to base 2..36 each Float
[that has k:=digits()] or each calculated number as %pi or %e or the division of
two float/int as in 1./3. ['oo' digits]

```
(15) -> h(%pi,13,800)
   (15)
  "3.1AC1049052A2C77369C0BB89CC9883278298358B370160306133CA5ACBA57614B65B410020
  C22B4C71457A955A5155B04A6CB6CC2C494843A8BBBBA9A039B77B34CB0C036CAC761129B3168
  B8BAB860134C419787C911812985646C7AAA3025BAA118B3AB8265CB347852065667291482145
  6C533447BC53A5262177C9985455C395626091A2CC3126B395C91B65B654A1804226197528410
  29A8A4A55CC7937B347B77B5A914127B11C6A57A84510775A9A467819A468B6B74339CC1290B2
  24921C6A771BC2AB6AB41735119C2231545A86399483119AAA5AC34B46B7B5C9089946A364860
  9B26CB0BAC0ABCBA182C12881933AA93C3942C71AA664753989A3C82166BA2109796C4A134607
  59725A72C9117AC980556A147557C319438287226C94725B125753B009387A48AA45CB1960A04
  A064052C00A6069371949872B14590895C555CB01A39B7589824B8621618A8B1971841201A2AB
  B04B80C7534CC1CB079581491995B46C679555316288C82665645A1A600C1A669B865651B6B842470C018B03C1115B3C4306C015C0B45C"
                                                             Type: String
```